# Convert array of objects with keys to keyed array

Tags: php, arrays, json, optimization

I have an array of objects that are defined as `{'preference name',value}`. For example

```
$preferences[] = {'abc',123};
$preferences[] = {'def',456};
```

I'd like to access them like this:

```
$pref = $preferences['abc'];
```

Of course, I know I could assign them as a keyed array to begin with, however I'm getting the values via JSON, and `json_decode` always creates an array of objects. Some example JSON that leads us to the situation above would be:

```
{'abc':123,'def':456}
```

Obviously it's trivial to covert these using a loop, but I wondered if there was a better one-liner that might do the job?

Comment: Decode as an associative array?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: I'm guessing some combination such as [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [get_object_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) will do the trick.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - that doesn't quite get it, does it?  It would just decode the sub-objects as associative arrays, leaving the top-level keys as a sequential numeric index?

Comment: so what is your actual JSON data? from your question above it makes it seem like you have different JSON data sets and you convert them into one using PHP (although `{}` is not proper PHP) . Is that the case? if not, can you provide your actual JSON sample data

Comment: Ok, but all properties need to be unique.

Comment: For me, @AbraCadaver had the best suggestion which I hadn't considered - using `json_decode($json,true)` which returned an associative array. Thank you all for your ideas though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decode the JSON into associative arrays AND all properties are unique, then just merge the sub arrays:

```
$preferences = json_decode($json, true);
$preferences = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $preferences);
```

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver The first line does exactly what I was after, I'm not sure why you'd use the second line though?

Comment: I still don't have a good idea of your data, but the second line was in response to _"that doesn't quite get it, does it? It would just decode the sub-objects as associative arrays, leaving the top-level keys as a sequential numeric index?"_

Answer (score 0):

Seems ugly, but hey, it works.

```
<?php

$a = ['abc'=>123,'def'=>456];
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($a));
var_dump($obj->abc); //123
$arr = (array)$obj;
var_dump($arr["abc"]); //123
```